# The sum of $n$ zero-mean values is of $O(\sqrt{n})$ at max

Tags: stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem, time-complexity

Why is the sum of $n$ zero-mean values is of $O(\sqrt{n})$ at max?

If $X$ is a random variable with a standard deviation $\sigma$, the standard deviation of $n$ such i.i.d. random variables is $\sqrt{n}\sigma$. But how does a standard deviation relate to an order ($O$)?
Is there an explanation for this without assuming the statistics of $X$ other than the fact that it's zero-meaned? I am looking for rigorous proof.

Comment: _Who_ says that the maximum of a sum of $n$ iid zero-mean random variables is $O(\sqrt{n})$? Could you provide a reference for this claim? Turning to the second paragraph, a function of $n$ is said to be $O(\sqrt{n})$ if it is bounded above by $c\sqrt{n}$ for some constant $c$, and so if your iid random variables have variance $\sigma$, the variance of the sum is $\sqrt{n}\sigma$ as you correctly state, and this is $O(\sqrt{n}$ since the functional form is $\sigma\sqrt{n}$ which is bounded above by $\sigma\sqrt{n}$. Note that zero-mean is _not_ required as it is in your assertion.

Comment: Thank you. The source is my advisor and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072517/show-the-sum-of-n-zero-mean-stationary-random-variables-is-bounded-by-mathcal

Comment: Also if the RV is not zero-mean, wouldn’t the summation be bounded by order n?